# Pain-free way to remove trailing commas in javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, editor

IE (<9?) doesn't tolerate trailing commas at the end of object or list.
I know this too late, after developing for a few months in Chrome.

Now I have to search for every place I put in a trail comma, this is really painful.
Is there any way(preferably automatic) to do this? Like a editor plugin, or some script that search and replace these commas with blank?

JSLint is an option, but it throws a lot of other warnings, and I have to paste in the scripts (which sometimes contain server-side template tags...).

Comment: Many text editors can replace text with RegExp.

Answer (score 1):

Some examples would have been good and which editor you use.

Notepad++ and UltraEdit support both Perl regular expression replaces with back referencing.

So you could try a Perl regular expression replace searching with the expression `,(\s*?[)\]])` and using `\1` as replace string.

This expression finds a comma before a closing round or square bracket with 0 or more spaces/tabs/line terminators between and keeps on replace everything except the comma.

You should run this replace manually on your JavaScript code with checking what is found before making the replace. And perhaps you need to run this replace several times in case of multiple commas at end of a list.